# How to display R.xml files in a fragment?

Tags: android

I was having this doubt of how to display a R.xml file in a fragment.

```
public class initSettings extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance)
{


return inflater.inflate(R.layout.init_settings,container,false);
}
```

}

Now, if I wanted to display R.xml.init_settings getting an error

```
Expected resource of type layout.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Expected resource of type `layout`.

You are trying to inflate xml file which it should be `layout` in this case in here:

```
(R.layout.init_settings, container, false);
```

So try to inflate this in the layout directory (just like your current codes):

```
R.layout.init_settings
```

And use layout to inflate and not an `xml`.

---

And like I said in my comments, `onCreateView()` won't import xml files. Instead, use `addPreferencesFromResource()` to inflate xml settings:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.init_settings);
    }
}
```

**Read the documentation:** https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#java

---

For the newest APIs (AndroidX) use `PreferenceFragmentCompat()`.

**Kotlin code:**

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settingspreference)


      }
    }
```

Comment: Well the xml file cant be in layout folder it has to be in xml folder, because its a preferencescreen xml file and the app will only work if these are in xml folders

Comment: Check the updated answer. I've provided everything you need.

Comment: getting cannot resolve symbol PreferenceFragmentCompat, theres no option to import library as well, only one option is to create a clas  called PreferenceFragmentCompat.

Comment: I'm using AndroidX that's why it uses `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. I'll update my answer for the older APIs. You should use: `PreferenceActivity` as mentioned in here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#java